# Scala UDF returning 'Schema for type Unit is not supported'

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to make changes to a column in the dataframe. The column is an Array for Integers. I want to replace an elements of the array, taking index from another array and replacing that element with an element from third array. Example: I have three columns C1, C2, C3 all three arrays. I want to replace elements in C3 as follows.

```
C3[C2[i]] = C1[i].
```

I wrote the following UDF:

```
def UpdateHist = udf((CRF_count: Seq[Long], Day: Seq[String], History: Seq[Int])=> for(i <- 0 to Day.length-1){History.updated(Day(i).toInt-1 , CRF_count(i).toInt)})
```

and executed this:

```
histdate3.withColumn("History2", UpdateHist2(col("CRF_count"), col("Day"), col("History"))).show()
```

But its returning an error as below:

```
scala> histdate3.withColumn("History2", UpdateHist2(col("CRF_count"), col("Day"), col("History"))).show()
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:733)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:671)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3100)
>     at UpdateHist2(:25)
>     ... 48 elided

I think I'm returning some different type, a View type which is not supported. Please help me how I can solve this.

Comment: For loop doesn't return anything so the function you use is `(Seq[Long], Seq[String], Seq[Int]) => Unit`

Comment: yes. How do I perform the update to the array then? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop returns a `Unit` hence the error message.  You could use `for-yield` to return values, but since the `Seq` should be `updated` successively, a simple `foldLeft` would work better:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (Seq(101L, 102L), Seq("1", "2"), Seq(11, 12)),
  (Seq(201L, 202L, 203L), Seq("2", "3"), Seq(21, 22, 23))
).toDF("C1", "C2", "C3")
// +---------------+------+------------+
// |C1             |C2    |C3          |
// +---------------+------+------------+
// |[101, 102]     |[1, 2]|[11, 12]    |
// |[201, 202, 203]|[2, 3]|[21, 22, 23]|
// +---------------+------+------------+

def updateC3 = udf( (c1: Seq[Long], c2: Seq[String], c3: Seq[Int]) =>
  c2.foldLeft( c3 ){ (acc, i) =>
    val idx = i.toInt - 1
    acc.updated(idx, c1(idx).toInt)
  }
)

df.withColumn("C3", updateC3($"C1", $"C2", $"C3")).show(false)
// +---------------+------+--------------+
// |C1             |C2    |C3            |
// +---------------+------+--------------+
// |[101, 102]     |[1, 2]|[101, 102]    |
// |[201, 202, 203]|[2, 3]|[21, 202, 203]|
// +---------------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: That's a brilliant one! Thanks!